# Why GitBash compilatiion is always with those warning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, webpack

almost from the beggining i have a big trouble with gitBash. Every compilation i got those warnings:

```
C:/Users/Mateusz/Desktop/Github-projects/react-tictactoe/node_modules/react-refresh/cjs/react-refresh-runtime.development.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\Github-projects\react-tictactoe\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--5-oneOf-3!C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\Github-projects\react-tictactoe\node_modules\react-refresh\cjs\react-refresh-runtime.development.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\Github-projects\react-tictactoe\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--5-oneOf-3!C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\Github-projects\react-tictactoe\node_modules\react-refresh\runtime.js
* C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\Github-projects\react-tictactoe\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--5-oneOf-3!C:\Users\Mateusz\desktop\github-projects\react-tictactoe\node_modules\react-refresh\cjs\react-refresh-runtime.development.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\Github-projects\react-tictactoe\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--5-oneOf-3!C:\Users\Mateusz\desktop\github-projects\react-tictactoe\node_modules\react-refresh\runtime.js

C:/Users/Mateusz/Desktop/Github-projects/react-tictactoe/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\Github-projects\react-tictactoe\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--5-oneOf-3!C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\Github-projects\react-tictactoe\node_modules\react-refresh\runtime.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\Github-projects\react-tictactoe\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--5-oneOf-3!C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\Github-projects\react-tictactoe\node_modules\@pmmmwh\react-refresh-webpack-plugin\client\ReactRefreshEntry.js
* C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\Github-projects\react-tictactoe\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--5-oneOf-3!C:\Users\Mateusz\desktop\github-projects\react-tictactoe\node_modules\react-refresh\runtime.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\Github-projects\react-tictactoe\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--5-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Mateusz\desktop\github-projects\react-tictactoe\src\index.js
```

What i tried to do:

- I checked a lot of time if i have correct imports(with big and small letters) in my files - Everything is ok, im 1000% suer about that.
- Deleting node modules folder and instlaing new one - nothing change.
  -changing my project folder and user folder for example mateusz => Mateusz and github-projects to Github-projects - nothing change.
- I was trying to create react app in another folder - 2 times. Nothing change.

What else i can do to fix this? I was checking multiple forum's and sites looking for the answer.

Comment: I assume the original code was written in Windows (outside of GitBash)? Windows is case insensitive, but typically "unix-like" systems like Git Bash are case sensitive. So perhaps the original code does indeed have casing issues that the Window developers never noticed. Just a guess.

Comment: @Michael Welch dont give answer base on guess, wait to be sure. If you don't know is better you do some search.

Comment: @Ustas I didn’t give an answer. I made a comment. If I was sure I would have posted an answer.

Comment: @Michael Welch then wait to be sure before you make a comment.

Comment: @Ustas There’s nothing wrong with my comment. I could have just as easily written it as a question: “ was the original code primarily developed in windows?” And then waited for a response and then answered. This is common in helping people and can provide a hint to others.